# An opaque object behind another object which is transparent leads to the opaque object becoming transparent

Tags: materials

Completely new to this corner of the internet.

I'm pretty new when it comes to Blender so been following different YouTube guides in order to understand some of the basics (I made a donut, obviously).

I've watched multiple tutorials now on how to make a transparent / glass object, which I've followed and I'm pretty happy with the result of the material.

I'm using the Cycles render engine.

However, I have an object with an opaque material behind this glass material, and now the opaque object is slightly transparent when behind the transparent material.

The green material is solid, a base colour of green, with none of the options changed.
The "glass" infront of it has a subsurface of 0.5, a transmission of 1, and a base colour of white, with an IOR of 1.4
[image]

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.

Many thanks!
Tom

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I don't see how the opaque material is/seems transparent.

Comment: I understand your problem but I can't re-create it - any attempt I make to recreate your setup yields an opaque green object whether or not it is behind a glass material (yours or a simple glass BSDF). What kind of lighting are you using? Also, what shape (roughly) is the glass object in the front (cylinder, plane, etc...)?